# Sign data with SoftHSM

Tags: sign, pkcs#11, hsm, softhsm

I want to sign (or encrypt) some data using SoftHSMv2 and pkcs11-tool.

So far, I generated a RSA keypair with :

```
 pkcs11-tool --module=/usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so -l --pin mypin -k --key-type rsa:1024 --id 01 --label mykey
```

But when I try to sign something :

```
 echo "some text" > input.txt
 pkcs11-tool --module=/usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so -l --pin mypin -s -i input.txt
```

I get the following error message :

```
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
error: Sign mechanism not supported
Aborting.
```

From what I understood reading the documentation, I should be able to sign with SoftHSM, but maybe I'm wrong ?

Is there an option to add during compilation or something else to fix my problem ? If not, is there other SSM products in the market ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten `-m (--mechanism)` option. Read more [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkcs11-tool).